# Clean architecture rxjava firebase implementation

Tags: android, rx-java2, clean-architecture

I'm using fernando cejas' clean android boilerplate code for my project and 
 implementing firebase realtime database to my project but, when I debug my code, I see that my emitter is **DISPOSED** everytime onDataChange() is called(when I add a new row to my firebase database), and my UI is not rendering the new list content, here's my data module code, any suggestions ?

```
@Override
public Observable<List> signalEntityList() {

Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");

return Observable.create(emitter -> {

  if (isThereInternetConnection()) {

    myFirebaseRef.child("signal").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<SignalEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = snapshot.getChildren();
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = snapshotIterable.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          SignalEntity signalEntity = iterator.next().getValue(SignalEntity.class);
          list.add(signalEntity);
        }

        emitter.onNext(list);
        emitter.onComplete();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
        emitter.onError(new FirebaseException(error.getMessage()));
      }
    });
  } else {
    emitter.onError(new NetworkConnectionException());
  }
});
}
```

Comment: You call `emmitter.onComplete` on data change. I think the observable is disposed when it is completed.

Comment: than you sir, I think the issue is solved. I cannot thank you enough, saved a lot of time.

Comment: @masp , could you please write your comment as an answer please, I will accept your reply as accepted answer. thank you.

Comment: You re welcome. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330776/combining-firebase-realtime-data-listener-with-rxjava). There are also a lot of libraries which try to combine Rxjava with firebase. The most important issue with your code is that you don't remove the value listener when the observable is disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are call onComplete() you told to Observable complete it work. And then you are subscribing - you thread in observable complete immediately.
Try to remove it, and i think you will get result you want.
And by the way, try to flatmap you list to iterable Observable.

```
@Override
public Observable<SignalEntity> signalEntityList() {

Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");

Observable<List<SignalEntity>> obs = Observable.create(emitter -> {

  if (isThereInternetConnection()) {

    myFirebaseRef.child("signal").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<SignalEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = snapshot.getChildren();
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = snapshotIterable.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          SignalEntity signalEntity = iterator.next().getValue(SignalEntity.class);
          list.add(signalEntity);
        }

        emitter.onNext(list);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
        emitter.onError(new FirebaseException(error.getMessage()));
      }
    });
  } else {
    emitter.onError(new NetworkConnectionException());
  }
});

return obs.flatMap(list -> {new Observable.from(list)})
}
```

Comment: hello @Scrobot, I dont have much background for rxjava, so could you please explain why to use flatmap and its benefits for my case ? thank you.

Comment: Hello. When you work with Observables, it can be more convenient if all of the data you mean to work with can be represented as Observables, rather than as a mixture of Observables and other types. This allows you to use a single set of operators to govern the entire lifespan of the data stream.  Iterables, for example, can be thought of as a sort of synchronous Observable.

Comment: It's means, that you can use single Model item and apply to it all operator you needed. If you want to map you data - you will map iterable item, but if it was list - you have to call list foreach iteration inside this map labmda-exprassion. It not comfortable for reading your code. I hope you will understand what i meen)

Comment: Observable.create is blocking? the control would move to return only with a call to emitter.onNext or emitter.onError?